# Git : how can i remove a particular commit from a branch

Tags: git

I have two brances namely master and development .
All the development will be done inside the development branch and will be merged with master for the build .

I checked out master branch and cherry picked 5 commits belonging to the development branch and pushed it to the master remote repository .

All these things went fine .

```
git checkout master 
git status
git cherry-pick a7644fc2bc7b09fe88cb1cbb75e0547dd1d7321d
git cherry-pick 335bf121a6aa7bc1e334b94d1a742b0f9ecfb9b6
git cherry-pick 5dee244a47d0346d5080ecd34984683c8f442c93
git cherry-pick 9f8fe22b346ba80089126afbf29ac063ea7b9b32
git cherry-pick 5dee244a47d0346d5080ecd34984683c8f442c9h
git push
```

Now my reqirement is  that i need to remove one of the cherry pick from the master to do the build .

I am not sure , but when i googled i found these two commands

```
git revert --strategy resolve

git rebase
```

Please let me know `how can i remove a particular commit` from the master branch

**Updated Part**

When i did git revert 564d01c3870ca5a55b171fc6f061e0cc2a8f4879 this screen came up , can i avoid this ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git revert <commit>`. If you do not want the editor to popup use `--no-edit` option. If you do not want to *actually* commit the revert, just apply it to your working directory, use the `--no-commit` option.

If you only pushed to controlled repository and you positively know nobody pulled from it then you can do some `git reset --hard <commit>^` and then re-cherry-pick the commits you actually want. But this is *not* recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much , but when i did git revert comitid , a nano screen came up , can i avoid that screen ??

Comment: The nano screen is the same screen you get when committing, i.e. it prompts you for a commit message, as you are essentially creating a commit that reverts the previous commit. You could use `git revert --no-edit <commit>` to prevent the screen but that will just use the message you saw before without giving you a chance to edit it.